# Match word(s) without title case in string - Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match with RegEx any word in this sequence (ex: 1943 The brown Fox Jumped) that is a string that starts with numbers and then after that has words with spaces between them. I have spent hours trying to figure out how to match any word in that sequence that isn't title cased (eg. The Brown Fox Jumped). I have figured out how to match if **all** words aren't title cased but not if one or two are in the middle of a sentence. How would I go about creating a regular expression to detect if one or more words aren't title cased?

The pattern that I am working with currently is `/(?<=^\d+\s)([a-z]+)/g`. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/mM5qK7/167) is a Regex101 demo of my last attempt. As mentioned earlier I figured out how to match if all of the words in the string weren't title cased as shown in [this](https://regex101.com/r/3RNVFE/2) Regex101 demo. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you want to match all words  with  lowercase letters `/(?<=^\d+\s.*?)\b[a-z]+\b/g`? See https://regex101.com/r/HxoBCq/1

Comment: Is regex required, I always have to wonder, seems there are very easy ways to do it without regex as well :)

Comment: @Icepickle Yes, it is required as it is for form validation.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I would like to match all words that are lowercased :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an infinite-width lookbehind based regex solution in case you must do it with a regex:

```
/(?<=^\d+\s.*?)\b[a-z]+\b/gs
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HxoBCq/2).

**Details**

- `(?<=^\d+\s.*?)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with

  - `^` - start of string
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `\s` - a whitespace]
  - `.*?`  - any 0 or more chars as few as possible
- `\b[a-z]+\b` - a whole word consisting of lowercase ASCII letters.

Note: this regex does not work in IE and older browsers that do not support the ECMAScript 2018+ standard.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
([A-Z])\w+
```

It matches all words with Capital letters in them.

This is actually the default example in Regex Generator. Test it here:

https://regexr.com/

[image]

Comment: Does not fit all the criteria needed

Comment: If this was your sentence:

1943 The brown Fox Jumped

What would your regex match?

Comment: It would match that but it wouldn't be able to verify if those numbers were in the front like they are

Comment: So it's supposed to identify a number at the beginning of the sentence and then capital words?